# How to execute bash commands form one bash to another bash process?

Tags: linux, bash, io, socat

I have two bash processes running. Let's name them bash_1 and bash_2. I wish to execute command in bash_1 from bash_2. I am following this method to achieve this.

Get the dev file for IO in bash_1

```
vchandola@mininet-server:~$ echo $$  
1097
vchandola@mininet-server:~$ ls -alh /proc/1097/fd  
total 0  
dr-x------ 2 vchandola vchandola  0 Jul 11 15:48 .  
dr-xr-xr-x 9 vchandola vchandola  0 Jul 11 15:48 ..  
lrwx------ 1 vchandola vchandola 64 Jul 11 15:48 0 -> /dev/pts/2  
lrwx------ 1 vchandola vchandola 64 Jul 11 15:48 1 -> /dev/pts/2  
lrwx------ 1 vchandola vchandola 64 Jul 11 15:48 2 -> /dev/pts/2  
lrwx------ 1 vchandola vchandola 64 Jul 11 16:08 255 -> /dev/pts/2
```

Execute following in bash_2 to execute commands in bash_2 to execute bash commands in bash_1

```
root@mininet-server:/home/vchandola# socat - /dev/pts/2
hello
ls
```

I was expecting responses of these in bash_2 but don't see them. In bash_1 both the strings have came but looks like Enter/newline character is not read/served as expected. This is what I see in bash_1

```
vchandola@mininet-server:~$ hello
ls
```

Why hello and ls commands were not executed in bash_1? What can I do to execute hello and ls in bash_1?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two shells, `shell-1` and `shell-2`:

```
(shell-1) $ who am i
user     pts/0        ...

(shell-2) $ who am i
user     pts/1        ...
```

Then *writing* to the associated character device will result in that output getting printed to the associated terminal (as you've seen):

```
(shell-2) $ echo hello > /dev/pts/0
$

(shell-1) $ hello
```

Writing to that device from `shell-2` is in no way different that writing to it from `shell-1`.  If you do a `echo hello` on `shell-1`, that also writes to `/dev/pts/0`, and that doesn't become *input* to that shell, it's written to the terminal's "screen".

If you want a process to write a shell's standard input stream, you'd need to use a different mechanism (e.g., a pipe or fifo), and that would need to be set up by the process that exec'ed the shell.